# If $T$ is a linear transformation on $V$,then which is true?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space with finite dimension $n$ and $T:V\longrightarrow V$ is a linear transformation such that $T^{2}=0$. Then

1. $rank(T)\leq\frac{n}{2}$
2. $n(T)\leq\frac{n}{2}$
3. $rank(T)\geq n(T)$
4. $rank(T)\geq \frac{n}{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sylvester's Rank Inequality $2\operatorname{rank}(T)-n\le \operatorname{rank}(T^2)=0$. $\operatorname{rank}(T)\le\frac{n}{2}$

and $\operatorname{rank}(T)+\operatorname{null}(T)=n$, so $\operatorname{null}(T)\ge \frac{n}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you mean $n(T)=\dim \ker T$.

1. **True**. This follows from [Sylvester's rank inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29#Properties):
   $$\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(B)-n\le \operatorname{rank}(AB)$$

2., 3., 4. **False**. Counterexample: $T=0$.

*Note:* 3. is true with the reverse inequality, because $T^2=0$ implies $\mathrm{im}\,T\subseteq\ker T$.